# Backbone.js Model Data Retrieval

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

General question if I am calling a webservice to return data related to one of my Backbone models.  Would it be better to call the webservice from within the model itself or should I pass in the results of the WS to the model on initialization.

I'm leaning towards incorporating the WS call within my model but then obviously may run into latency issues.

So where is the best place to handle this data retrieval?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the page that is rendering your HTML already knows the data that will go into your model, I definitely prefer rendering the data right into the model constructor.  Something like this (assuming a Rails view, but that is just for the purpose of illustration):

Let's assume your controller has rendered some JSON data as `@modelData`.

```
var modelData = <%= @modelData %>;
var model = new TheModel(modelData);
```

Doing it this way allows you to have your data immediately and not require a second call back to the service.  I have used this approach several times with a lot of success.

**Edit**

To expand on this, this results in fewer calls to the server because the back end is rendering the data in the HTML or JS that gets returned to the client.  The result (after view rendering) of the above code might be something like this:

```
var modelData = {id: 5, first: "Collin", last: "Estes" }; // populated in first server call
var model = new TheModel();
```

If you to it the other way, however, you make two calls to the server:

```
var model = new TheModel({id: 5});
model.fetch();  // results in second server call
```

The first call to the server is the one returning your code.  The second happens when you call fetch.

*If you are asking something else, then I apologize.  You might clarify what you mean by "where is the best place to handle these calls".*

Comment: +1 This is the way to go for setting the initial value of the JS models. -- Fewer calls to the server means faster web pages for the user. Remember that you can (in the view) output as JSON for assigning complex data structures in the JS.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  Why would this equal fewer calls to the server?  I'm going to have to make the same amount of calls to my server I'm only wondering where is the best place to handle these calls.  I guess Brian you are saying I should handle them prior to the instantiation of my model and pass in all the necessary data in with the constructor?

Comment: @CollinEstes I have expanded my answer to explain why it results in fewer server calls.  I might be misunderstanding your question, though.

Comment: This is a little tangential and doesn't really answer the question.  Yes fewer calls is better in certain circumstances but what he's asking is a design question about when to create objects, before or after the data arrives.

Comment: @BrianNickel How am I not answering his question?  He is asking if he should "pass in the results of the WS to the model on initialization."  I am saying "yes" but do it on the server instead of a separate call to pass it in.  I then show how to do it.  It is, in my opinion, better than calling `fetch()` up front.

Comment: Sorry, I read the question differently, that he is doing everything with JavaScript.  That is, he is currently using an AJAX call to pull the data and is then passing it though the constructor.  In that case, `fetch` would be smarter.  In general, though, for larger applications I would still rather use `fetch` even if we have the data available.  I would have Backbone.sync leverage `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` as a cache and use the available model to prime the cache.  This makes refactoring a lot easier.

Comment: Gotcha.  One of the great things about Backbone is its flexibility to fit into a wide range of architectures.  Whether you populate in the page or call fetch, there are several scenarios where the data capture works well.

Comment: Thanks Brian this makes more sense to me now.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do this is to create the model first and then use `model.fetch` to pull the data.  That way all your ajax logic is consolidated in `Backbone.sync`.

If you have the data readily available at the time you render the HTML, I would place it into a cache, for example `sessionStorage`, and have your syncing code able to read from/write to the cache.  That way if you ever need to move the web service call out of the HTML rendering (e.g., if you're using an application cache), you don't need to do a major refactoring.